# Programatically adding new CKeditor instance

Tags: 8, wysiwyg

What is the trick to ckeditor in D8? It's woefully under documented and CKEDITOR / CKEDITOR.instances seemingly return nothing, despite showing multiple instances of ckeditor instances available. CKEDITOR.replace() seems to give a config error (missing 404 js files) when you try to target an element.

I can target and get data back for CKEDITOR.dom.element.get('edit-comment-body-0-value') but once try to use getEditor(), it automatically returns NULL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not supposed to use the CKEditor API directly. You could do that if you want to use CKEditor on something you control. But your DOM ID (`edit-comment-body-0`) indicates you're trying to do this for a "Formatted text" field in Drupal 8, which uses the filter system.
If you'd want to attach CKEditor manually, use the JS API provided by `core/modules/editor/js/editor.js`.

The integration between Drupal 8 and CKEditor is very solid/deep, in that Drupal 8 automatically configures CKEditor to match the text format's filter settings. And that integration is not tightly coupled to CKEditor: there's the Text Editor (`editor`) module that allows any text editor to integrate in a similarly deep way. But it means you should always use the APIs that `editor` provides.

For API docs, see:

- https://www.drupal.org/developing/api/8/editor
- https://www.drupal.org/developing/api/8/ckeditor
- https://www.drupal.org/developing/api/8/filter

For the concrete relevant code, see [`TextFormat`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21filter%21src%21Element%21TextFormat.php/class/TextFormat/8), [`editor_element_info_alter()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21editor%21editor.module/function/editor_element_info_alter/8) and [`\Drupal\Editor\Element::preRenderTextFormat`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21editor%21src%21Element.php/function/Element%3A%3ApreRenderTextFormat/8).